# С++: Перегрузка оператора [] в классе массив для изменения элемента

Tags: c++, массивы, классы, c++11, перегрузка-операторов

Реализовать перегрузку оператора `[]` для класса массив не составляет труда,если нужно элемент массива просто получить, а как реализовать перегрузку оператора `[]` для реализации вида:

```
intArray a(5);
a[0]=5;
a[1]=10; 
// и т.д.
```

Буду благодарна за ответ или ссылку на ответ.

Comment: Вопрос решен, спасибо за помощь :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если есть класс и нужно перегрузить `оператор []` для элементов класса имеющих тип `T`, то оператор перегружается обычно следующим образом

```
T & operator []( size_t );
```

и

```
const T & operator []( size_t ) const;
```

Первый оператор позволяет изменять переданный по ссылке элемент класса, а второй позволяет работать с константными объектами.

Обратите внимание, что следует одновременно определить оба этих оператора в классе.

Для скалярных типов, когда копирование объектов является простой операцией, то можно второй оператор также определить как

```
T operator []( size_t ) const;
```

То есть он будет возвращать временный объект.

Как я понимаю, для вашего случая типом `T` будет служить тип `int`.

Также вы можете перегрузить оператор, когда параметром является список инициализации.

Ниже показана демонстрационная программа.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>

class Array
{
public:
    Array() : n(0), a(nullptr) {}

    explicit Array(size_t n) : n(n), a(nullptr)
    {
        if (n) a = new int[n]();
    }

    Array(size_t n, int value ) : n(n), a(nullptr)
    {
        if (n)
        {
            a = new int[n];
            std::fill(a, a + n, value);
        }
    }

    Array(const Array &a) : n(0), a(nullptr)
    {
        if (a.n)
        {
            this->a = new int[a.n];
            this->n = a.n;
            std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), this->begin());
        }
    }

    ~Array() { delete a; }

    size_t size() const { return n; }

    const int & operator [](size_t i) const
    {
        return a[i];
    }

    int & operator [](size_t i)
    {
        return a[i];
    }

    Array operator [](std::initializer_list<size_t> lst) const
    {
        Array a(lst.size());
        size_t i = 0;

        for ( size_t j : lst )
        {
            a.a[i++] = this->a[j];
        }

        return a;
    }

    int * begin() { return a; }

    const int * begin() const { return a; }

    int * end() { return a + n; }

    const int * end() const { return a + n; }

private:
    size_t n;
    int *a;
};


int main()
{
    const int N = 10;

    Array a(N);
    int i = N;

    for (auto &x : a) x = --i;
    for (auto x : a) std::cout << x << ' ';

    std::cout << std::endl;

    Array b = a[{ 0, 2, 4, 6, 8}];

    for (auto x : b) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
9 7 5 3 1
```

В этом примере определены три оператора `operator []`

```
    const int & operator [](size_t i) const;

    int & operator [](size_t i);

    Array operator [](std::initializer_list<size_t> lst) const;
```

Я класс определил по минимуму. Например, в нем отсутствует копирующий оператор присваивания. Вы можете самостоятельно его написать.

Чтобы код компилировался в MS Visual Studio, вам необходимо включить макрообъявление в заголовочный файл `<stdafx.h>` следующим образом

```
#pragma once

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
//...
```

Comment: Благодарю за столь подробный ответ!

Comment: @kariishka Не за что. Спрашивайте еще.:)

Answer (score 5):

Если для получения вы определяете оператор как

```
int operator[](size_t index);
```

то для того, чтобы и получать значение, и присваивать, его нужно определить как ссылку:

```
int& operator[](size_t index);
```